# how to simplify/expand $(x - 1/2)^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Last night, I was quite tired and asked the incorrect question for the expansion of:
$$\left(x-\frac12\right)^2$$

the actual question was $$\left(x-\frac12\right)^x$$

as a multiple choice question, i chose the answer:

$$x^2+\frac2x$$

sorry for the repeat,
Thank you.

potentially,$$\left(\frac12\right)^x$$ you multiply by the reciprocal of x and $$\frac12$$? so: $$\frac21times\frac1xexquals 2x$$ ?

Comment: If $x$ is a positive integer, we can get a messy expression using the Binomial Theorem. In general we can write it as $\exp(x\ln(x-1/2))$, where $\exp(t)=e^t$. Perhaps you are not giving the full question.

Comment: If both the base and the exponent vary then your options are limited. Since you say it was a multiple choice question, why not post the full thing verbatim, choice-list and all?

Comment: I only wrote down what i could remember from an in class placement test via computer :/ i don't believe i wrote down my answer correct either

Answer (score 1):

You have $$x^x (1-\frac{1}{2x})^x$$ You can now expand this using Newton's generalization of the binomial theorem under the condition $|\frac{1}{2x}|<1$.

So the expression you will get is $$x^x[1+x(-\frac{1}{2x})+\frac{x(x-1)}{2!}(-\frac{1}{2x})^2 + \frac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{3!}(-\frac{1}{2x})^3 +\dots]$$